# Is there a FLASH editor that supports autocomplete & step-into debugging?

Tags: flash, actionscript, ide, autocomplete

I'm considering using Flash but I'm pretty addicted to autocomplete and Step-at-a-time debugging.

Answer (score 3):

By using Eclipse with the ActionScript plugin you get full code hinting in the same format that you do with intellisense.

Or you can use [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/) that has both intellisense and can [debug (trace) your code](http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?p=6105).

Answer (score 0):

If you mean ActionScript I once heard that [PrimalScript](http://www.primalscript.com/) will do Intellisense. Never tested it though. As for debugging, MAYBE, [PrimalScope](http://www.primalscope.com/) will have that too. I'd recommend you try before you buy, though. (They both have trials.)

Answer (score 0):

FDT is a plugin for Eclipse which many say (including myself) is the best editor when it comes to writing actionscript. FDT supports as2 & as3, including the new apis from Flash player 10. I haven't used Visual Studio myself but i'm guessing it's pretty much the same regarding intellisense (all versions of FDT). FDT Enterprise also supports debugging including breakpoints and stepping through your code (= not just trace).

http://fdt.powerflasher.com/

Answer (score 0):

Both FlexBuilder and Flash CS3 have autocompletion and debuggers that can step through code one line at a time. Both can be used to develop in pure ActionScript (i.e. FlexBuilder isn't just for writing Flex applications).

Answer (score 0):

it will be cool to have autocompletion  in flash CS3 like the one that comes with eclipse for java (with hints, hierarchies , implementation, autoimports for clases etc . .), i dont know why everyone wants to separate the code from graphical editor , when thats the best part of flash , anyway i always recommend to stay with eclipse since it is very robust and its available for a lot of languages so in case you need to learn other language you already know the IDE and how to use autocompletion.

Answer (score 0):

[FlashDevelop](http://flashdevelop.org) is a lightweight Flash editor but it doesn't have a debugger. But FlexBuilder is a much popular and full-featured.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe has said that the next version of Flash (CS5) will have a lot of coding improvements, including code hinting, auto-complete, and auto-import for custom classes. But whether it will pull even with Eclipse and FlashDevelop is still an open question.